# Using pipes to redirect the output from 'seq' to the input of 'awk'

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe, posix

In a child process I call `seq` with `1` as first argument and the first command line argument as a a second argument. Then I proceed to use the stdout of `seq` as input for the second command `awk`. That command gets the second command line argument as an argument. Error checking is not relevant for this task so please concentrate on the functionality.

In the end the output of `awk` should be printed on stdout.

It shall simulate something like: `seq 1 10 | awk {printf}`

This is how far I came but I get no output:

```
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int fd1[2];

if (pipe(fd1)==-1){ 
    fprintf(stderr, "Pipe Failed"); 
    return -1; 
}

int pidSeq = fork();
if(pidSeq == 0){
    close(fd1[READ]);
    dup2(fd1[WRITE], 1);
    close(fd1[WRITE]);
    execl("seq", "seq", "1", argv[1], NULL);
}
else if(pidSeq > 0){
    close(fd1[WRITE]);
    dup2(fd1[READ], 0);
    close(fd1[READ]);
    execl("awk", "awk", argv[2], NULL);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error checking is always important if you have a problem. If you have no problem, you can sometimes survive without error checking. If you have a problem, maybe the problem is one of the errors you didn't check.

Comment: I want to understand the principle how I can pass the output of one command to the input of another command. Simple as that. I know when writing a real application, error checking is important but I don't want the answers here to get away from the functionality point which is where I'm struggling.

Comment: I'll say it again because I don't think you read my comment the first time: Error checking is always important if you have a problem. If you have no problem, you can sometimes survive without error checking. If you have a problem, maybe the problem is one of the errors you didn't check.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't because of an error. But maybe the problem is one of the errors you didn't check.

Comment: So is the functional procedure in my example right? If you have knowledge of Unix pipes and c programming you should be able to tell me if my thoughts on this task are right, shouldn't you? That would be helpful because If the functional procedure is right, then we can look at error checking. If the functional procedure is already wrong we don't need to waste time on checking for errors which will lead to nothing because the whole program wouldn't do what it's supposed to do anyway.

Comment: I do not see any mistakes, but that doesn't mean there aren't any.

Comment: Actually, I see a mistake now. You will see it too if you check for errors. If you had done that before, then you would not need to ask Stack Overflow. I rest my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `execlp()` instead of `execl()`.

As written, it will only work if the current directory contains both `seq` and `awk`.

Note that if you had reported an error if the `execl()` functions return (and they only return on error; they do not return if they succeed), then you would have known what was going wrong without needing to ask.

Here's a fixed version of your code.  It uses some code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  This simplifies the error reporting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc != 3)
        err_usage("max 'awk script'");

    int fd1[2];
    if (pipe(fd1) == -1)
        err_syserr("failed to create a pipe: ");

    int pidSeq = fork();
    if (pidSeq == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[READ]);
        dup2(fd1[WRITE], 1);
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        execlp("seq", "seq", "1", argv[1], NULL);
        err_syserr("failed to exec 'seq': ");
    }
    else if (pidSeq > 0)
    {
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        dup2(fd1[READ], 0);
        close(fd1[READ]);
        execlp("awk", "awk", argv[2], NULL);
        err_syserr("failed to exec 'awk': ");
    }
    else
        err_syserr("failed to fork(): ");

    return 0;
}
```

It was compiled from `seq-awk59.c` into `seq-awk59` and then run as:

```
$ seq-awk59 15 '{sum += $1}END{print sum}'
120
$
```

I first used a version with `execl()` instead of `execlp()`.  The output I got was:

```
$ seq-awk59 15 '{sum += $1}END{print sum}'
seq-awk59: failed to exec 'awk': error (2) No such file or directory
seq-awk59: failed to exec 'seq': error (2) No such file or directory
$
```

And misusing the program generates a usage message:

```
$ seq-awk59 a b c
Usage: seq-awk59 max 'awk script'
$
```